# C qsort strange behaviour

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Allocate memory for array of dimension 7
2. Write the first 4 positions
3. Sort those 4 positions.
4. Write the remaining 3 positions
5. Sort the entire array.

I have the array `(1,6,2,3)`, which after sorting becomes `(1,2,3,6)`

Then I write the remaining positions, which are `(1,2,3,6,1,5,1)`

After sorting it, I should be getting `(1,1,1,2,3,5,6)`, but instead I'm getting 
`(6,2,3,1,1,5,1)`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int comp(const void* a, const void* b);

typedef struct{

    int peso;
 }aresta_;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    aresta_* array /*struct array, has field peso of type int*/;
    int dim=7;
    int dim_aux=4;
    int i;

    array = (aresta_*) malloc(dim * sizeof(aresta_));

    array[0].peso=1;
    array[1].peso=6;
    array[2].peso=2;
    array[3].peso=3;


    printf("First sort:\n");
    for(i=0; i<dim_aux; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i].peso);

    printf("\n");


    qsort(array, dim_aux, sizeof(array[0]), comp);


    for(i=0; i<dim_aux; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i].peso);

    printf("\n\n");

    array[4].peso=1;
    array[5].peso=5;
    array[6].peso=1;

    printf("Second sort:\n");


    for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i].peso);

    printf("\n");

    qsort(array, dim, sizeof(array[0]), comp);

    for(i=0; i<dim; i++)
        printf("%d ",array[i].peso);




    printf("\n");

}
```

My comp function:

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    aresta_* a1 = (aresta_*)a;
    aresta_* b1 = (aresta_*)b;
    return a1->peso > b1->peso;
}
```

**The Output:**

```
First sort:
1 6 2 3 
1 2 3 6 

Second sort:
1 2 3 6 1 5 1 
6 2 3 1 1 5 1 
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Where did I go wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your compare function only returns 0 or 1, when it should return a positive, a negative, or a zero `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane That was it. Because it worked on the first sort, I assumed I was messing up somewhere else. Guess it didn't work when a==b. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can `return a1->peso - b1->peso;` but that may cause arithmetic overflow. Better to be in the habit of `if(a1->peso > b1->peso) return 1; ... ` etc.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yep, I went with the if's and it's now working as intended. Thank you once again.

Comment: @WeatherVane `return a1->peso > b1->peso;` is exactly the same as `if(a1->peso > b1->peso) return 1 else return 0;`

Comment: @4386427 no it is not. I will spell out for you the `...` in my above comment that the OP understood perfectly. `if(a1->peso > b1->peso) return 1; if(a1->peso < b1->peso) return -1; return 0;`

Comment: @4386427 there are three possibilities as defined by the requirements for the comparison function: `a < b`, `a > b`, and `a == b`. You cannot get three values from one comparison.

Comment: The 2nd class one-liner compare function is `return (a<b) ? -1 : a > b;`

Comment: @chux nice too but my brain still prefers to read the former. It hates decoding the ternary thing, which I think subverts the point of a programming language providing a bridge between the way we think and the way computers work. (Aside so I binned C++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's function only returned 0 and 1. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723947/c-qsort-strange-behaviour/43724976#comment74491704_43723947)

As this "worked" for OP for the first 4 values is "luck".

The compare function needs to return 1 of 3 results: negative, 0 or positive.

> The function shall return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
>   C11dr §7.22.5.2 3

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    const aresta_* a1 = (const aresta_*)a;
    const aresta_* b1 = (const aresta_*)b;
    // return a1->peso > b1->peso;
    return (a1->peso > b1->peso) - (a1->peso < b1->peso);
}
```

`return (a1->peso > b1->peso) - (a1->peso < b1->peso);` has advantages over `return a1->peso - b1->peso;`.  This answer does not overflow.  It is valid and functionally correct for all pairs of `int`.  Various compilers recognize this idiom and produce tight code.  `int - int` can overflow which is *undefined behavior*, UB.

Comment: Note: I prefer `const aresta_*` over `aresta_*`.  This avoids some compiler warnings that complain about casting away `const`-ness of `const void*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    aresta_* a1 = (aresta_*)a;
    aresta_* b1 = (aresta_*)b;
    ---->   return a1->peso > b1->peso;  <---- Watch carefully out! What it does!
}
```

The return line just checks merely greater or not. If,

- `a1->peso` is greater, it returns 1
- `b1->peso` is greater, it returns 0 (*It is also not right result because zero must mean equal*)
- *What about equality case that the values equal each other?*

You didn't check the last case. To do you can write with if-else cases like

```
if(a1->peso > b1->peso) {
//  ....
} else if (a1->peso < b1->peso) {
// ....
} else {
// equality case....
}
```

or simply do `return a1->peso - b1->peso` giving expected result that

- `> 0` so positive
- `< 0` so negative
- `== 0` so equal each other

---

According to chux nicely drawing attention to overflow point, it can be handled for overflow case.

```
#include <limits.h>

if ((b1->peso > 0 && a1->peso < INT_MIN + b1->peso) ||
      (b1->peso < 0 && a1->peso > INT_MAX + b1->peso)) {
    /* Handle error */
} else {
    return a1->peso - b1->peso;
}
```